# Unable to download files from self hosted Parse-Server on DigitalOcean

Tags: nginx, parse-server, pffile

I have migrated my App from Parse.com to self hosted Parse-Server on DigitalOcean with SSL. Everything works nicely except when I try to download any file which were uploaded on my parse-server I get error.
If I try to access it from iPhone App I get error saying **"CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)"** and on Safari it says **"Safari cannot establish secure connection to server"**

All the files have URL something like this - **"https://domain_name.com:1337/parse/files/.....file.bin"**
However if the change the link to look something like this - **"http://www.domain_name.com:1337/parse/files/.....file.bin"** It gets downloaded in Safari.

Any idea what is the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your SSL certificate valid for that domain, not expired and not a self-signed one?

Comment: Yes SSL certificate is valid for my domain and it is signed by **Let's Encrypt**. Also I am able to fetch textual data from parse-server without any issue.

Comment: Can you share a real URL so others can see what exactly is going on? It can be hard to tell just from a fairly generic error message and a dummy URL

Comment: Hi Björn Kaiser, This is real URL of an image. However now when I try to download file by modifying the URL it has stopped working. Don't know what is going on. Please help...  https://cobbet.com:1337/parse/files/IpFrZ8h4ZFjv9fKhUq3p7C2ca2WOBuAkbbzmtrxe/50c99849-9e31-4414-9552-f640fb43eb53_iphone_6.png

Comment: I think yesterday when I modified my Nginx server config that might have caused it (downlaoding file by modifying URL) to stop working.

Comment: I think the issue is with my Nginx server configuration and not with parse-server

Comment: Now when i replace my domain-name with server URL like this  http://104.236.228.111:1337/parse/files/IpFrZ8h4ZFjv9fKhUq3p7C2ca2WOBuAkbbzmtrxe/50c99849-9e31-4414-9552-f640fb43eb53_iphone_6.png I am able to download the file